# Subdomain and Uploadify not working

Tags: javascript, .htaccess, uploadify, wildcard-subdomain

I have wildcard subdomains for example:

*.example.com goes to example.com/app/*

It seems uploadify works fine if I use the directory instead of the subdomain. But when I use the subdoman and click on the upload image nothing happens. It seems to load the flash fine and no JS errors but when I click on the button I do not get a file browser. Maybe the way I do the wildcard domains affects it, not sure. here is my htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*).example.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/app/%1/$1 [P]
```

I also use the full path to call the js and flash files. They are not located under the subdomain but under the root domain. So I just use the full url path, here is an example of my js:

```
$("#fileInput").uploadify({
      'uploader'       : 'http://example.com/js/upload/_scripts/uploadify.swf',
      'script'         : 'http://sub.example.com/discuss/upload/do_upload/' + session_id,
      'cancelImg'      : 'http://example.com/images/icons/del.png',
      'folder'         : '/files/',
      'multi'          : true,
                'auto' : true,
                'queueSizeLimit' : 10,
                'buttonImg' : 'http://example.com/images/attachafile2.jpg',
                'width' : 91,
                'height' : 23,
                'wmode' : 'transparent'
   });
```

Comment: It's possible you're hitting a cross-domain violation in JavaScript by trying to access your sub-domain. Not sure on this though.

Comment: Im not really sure. I tried to find the bottleneck by seeing if I could break it in the directory version but no go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

uploadify uses flash to perform the upload.  Flash is subject to the same origin policy, much like a native browser, except that it has a loophole.

Flash will look for a file called [crossdomain.xml](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/articles/crossdomain_policy_file_spec.html) at the root of the webserver.  This XML file dictates which other domains may access its contents via flash.

For example, here is [twitter's crossdomain file](http://api.twitter.com/crossdomain.xml)

It may be sufficient in your case to create or modify this file to accept connections from the various domains involved.

Good luck!

Comment: Thats what I figured out after playing around more. I changed the way some stuff was setup and it seemed to work now.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the Wikipedia entry for the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) it sounds to like this won't work because sub.domain.com != domain.com as far as JavaScript is concerned. That being said, it also [sounds like](http://www.hostingrails.com/Using-mod_rewrite-or-mod_proxy-to-avoid-the-Same-Origin-Policy) that so long as JavaScript *believes* it's requesting the same domain everything should be just peachy.

I *think* if you **tell Uploadify to post to the original not-rewritten-path** and allow Apache to handle the rewrite automatically, then JavaScript won't think it's violating the same origin policy.

**For example:** If you remapped `domain.com/path/to/foo` to `foo.domain.com` and then in your JavaScript request `/path/to/foo`, Apache will translate the request accordingly and JavaScript won't know the difference.